# Creating a macro-enabled Excel file from within Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The following code, when used within Word VBA, successfully creates a standard Excel workbook in the chosen folder:

```
Const ExcelSourcePath = "C:\Users\Holge\_Universet i billeder\_ExcelDocs\"
Dim xlAppl As New Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As New Excel.Workbook

Private Sub TestCreateExcelFile()
    Set xlAppl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlAppl.Workbooks.Add
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlBook.SaveAs FileName:=ExcelSourcePath & "TestFile.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    xlBook.Close False
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    xlAppl.Quit
    Set xlAppl = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, what I really need is to create a macro-enabled file. But if I change ".xlsx" into ".xlsm" I get a RTE 1004, "Wrong file type name" (translated from Danish).
Perhaps CreateObject should be called with another argument, but which one? I have not been alble to find possible values for this argument.

Comment: You would need to add the Format argument to your `SaveAs` line... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Comment: Side note: If you declare `Dim xlAppl As New Excel.Application`, you have already created an Excel App object (using Early Binding). No need to call `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` which will create another Excel App object (this time using Late Binding).

Answer (score 1):

In the following code:

```
Dim xlAppl As New Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As New Excel.Workbook

Private Sub TestCreateExcelFile()
    Set xlAppl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlAppl.Workbooks.Add
```

A new Excel Application instance is created twice. You need to keep the one line of code for create a new instance, not doing that twice.

Moreover, an instance of the `Workbook` class can't be created by using the `New` operator like shown in your code:

```
Dim xlBook As New Excel.Workbook
```

Most probably the intention was to declare objects out of the sub and then instantiate them:

```
Const ExcelSourcePath = "C:\Users\Holge\_Universet i billeder\_ExcelDocs\"
Dim xlAppl As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook

Private Sub TestCreateExcelFile()
    Set xlAppl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlAppl.Workbooks.Add
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlBook.SaveAs FileName:=ExcelSourcePath & "TestFile.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    xlBook.Close False
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    xlAppl.Quit
    Set xlAppl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Just need to remove `New` operators from the code with declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Const ExcelSourcePath = "C:\Users\Holge\_Universet i billeder\_ExcelDocs\"
Dim xlAppl As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook

Private Sub TestCreateExcelFile()
    Set xlAppl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlAppl.Workbooks.Add
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlBook.SaveAs FileName:=ExcelSourcePath & "TestFile.xlsx",_
                  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    xlBook.Close False
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    xlAppl.Quit
    Set xlAppl = Nothing
End Sub
```